# What are the ramifications of using interior oil-based paint outdoors?

Tags: paint, repainting

I accidentally spray painted some gates for my deck with interior oil-based paint.  They had been previously painted and I was touching them up after about 7 years use.  I put 2 coats of the oil-based interior paint on them.  They are white.  I'm wondering what I should do.  Would it make any difference to put a coat of exterior paint on top?  Should I just put them outside and wait for them to wear out again?

Comment: Any interior paint I have seen used outside has fell off

Comment: well, i'm going to give it a coat of exterior semi-gloss and see how it does.  i'll report back every year or so.  :)

Comment: so far so good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used oil based indoor paints many times outdoors.  Mainly on sheds.  The only issue I have had with it is an extreme amount of discoloration.  Bright blue turned to really dull pool liner blue, off white turned to dirty-light-yellow.

Honestly I would leave it be for now.  If you painted over other latex it might just fall off once it fully hardens and hits a few temp changes.  That will make scraping it easier.  If it doesn't fall off then just see what happens.  It isn't hurting anything.

Answer (score 1):

One big difference between interior and exterior paint is the flexibility.  Interior paint does not have to deal with as drastic of temperature changes.  Odds are after a summer the oil based paint (even if you put a coat over the top) will get very brittle and begin to crack, particularly if the paint did no go onto bare wood.

Answer (score 1):

Most exterior rated paints incorporate UV inhibitors to protect against the sun's harsh rays, while interior rated paints do not. So I'd expect discoloration and premature deterioration.